# How can I get my printer driver to install on Windows 7 again

Tags: windows, printing, driver, signing

For some years we used a Comodo SHA-1 code signing certificate to sign the .cat file of our Windows printer driver. The built signed driver installed fine on XP up to Windows 10. On systems that have never seen the driver before we get the expected warning dialog asking if the user trusts us, the author of the driver. 
So everything's been fine up til now.

Unfortunately, that certificate just expired, and since SHA-1 certificates are deprecated, the supplied replacement certificate is SHA-2.

The only thing that has changed in our build is the certificate. The build still produces a signed driver, and that driver behaves **the same as before, i.e. absolutely fine, on Windows 8 and up**. But on Windows 7, even after installing the Windows patch to make it understand SHA-2, at driver-install time we now get the scary red warning dialog saying the driver is unsigned.

My question is - is there anything I can do get the driver to install without the scary warning on Windows 7 with the Windows SHA-2 patch installed?

Comment: Once again, I'm mystified why the question has been anonymously downvoted without comment. I'd really love an answer to this question, so please tell me how to frame it so that I get one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once I'd added the comodo-supplied cross certificate to the Intermediate Certification Authorities store on the build machine I was able to rebuild the driver so that it installed on Win7x64 without any scary red warnings.